# How to Change Position Of Element from fixed to relative when it reaches its original position in Dom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a website where i want to change the position of element from fixed to relative when it reaches its original position.

You can check the webpage here --> http://www.countertack.com/homepage-2014?hs_preview=NPDotwST-1103539158

There is a red bar at the bottom of page which is fixed in position, but i want to change it to relative when scroll reaches footer(black section in bottom).

I am not good at jquery or javascript so any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
.fixed-cta{
    background:#d32823;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

Comment: I updated code,fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.fixed-cta').toggleClass('relative', $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - $('.your-black-footer').height());
});
```

All you need to do is replace `your-black-footer` with the class name of your footer, and use the following CSS:

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

updated Working fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23raZ/1/)
Use following code :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $(".fixed-cta").css({position: "relative"});
   }else{
       $(".fixed-cta").css({position: "fixed"});
   }

});
```

If reached to the bottom ,make position relative.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro, but i need to get back to position fixed when scrolls up too, you can check the webpage again after implementing your code. You can see the exact position of fixed-cta

Comment: u mean if i scroll up then again ,position fixed?

Comment: @VikasGhodke Even if you are not experienced in Jquery you should be able to deduce what you are asking from this answer.

Comment: If the answer solved ur Question ,please ,you can accept it as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Following code worked for me

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if (
        $(window).scrollTop() >=
        $(".div").offset().top +
        $(".div").outerHeight() - window.innerHeight
    ) {
        console.log("condition matched");
        $(".fixed-cta").css({ position: "absolute" });
    } 
    else $(".fixed-cta").css({ position: "fixed" });
});
```